# Why does the expansion of this partial derivate give the following result?

Tags: partial-derivative

$$(\cos \phi \frac \partial {\partial \rho} - \frac {\sin \phi} \rho \frac \partial {\partial \phi})(\cos \phi \frac {\partial g} {\partial \rho} - \frac {\sin \phi} \rho \frac {\partial g} {\partial \phi}) $$
$$=\cos ^2 \phi \frac {\partial ^2 g} {\partial \rho ^2} + \frac {2 \cos \phi \sin \phi} {\rho ^2} \frac {\partial g} {\partial \phi} - \frac {2 \cos \phi \sin \phi} \rho \frac {\partial ^2 g} {\partial \phi \partial \rho} + \frac {\sin ^2 \phi} \rho \frac {\partial g} {\partial \rho} + \frac {\sin ^2 \phi} {\rho ^2} \frac {\partial ^2 g} {\partial \phi ^2}$$
[photo of the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roJ5o.png)

I can't wrap my head around how this is the result yielded by the expansion. I understand where the first and last terms come from, but not the others. Apologies if the answer is trivial, I might not be seeing something here.

The broader context of this questions entails relating Cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates via a partial derivate.

Comment: What result do you get instead?

Comment: The $\partial/\partial\phi$ in the first parentheses, when applied to the term involving $\phi$ in the second parentheses, produces (via the product rule) a term involving $\partial(\sin\phi)/\partial\phi$. I expect that all the terms you  missed arise similarly from the product rule.